# In Web_Scraping the list is returning empty list

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, webscarab

```
import requests
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

url = "https://www.covid19india.org/"
headers = {"Accept-Language":"en-US, en;q=0.5"}
results = requests.get(url,headers = headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(results.text,"html.parser")
cases_div = soup.find_all('div', class_="Level1")
print(cases_div)
```

My expect output is the HTML

However, I am getting an empty list while printing cases_div.

Why is that and how can I fix it?

Comment: This is normal: this website/request only provide script. You should try a sofware like postman to try various requests

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the specified website uses React, and on the first HTTP request you will not get the whole content. 
Try to use selenium or try to find the API requests to the server as was suggested in the comment.

Comment: soup = BeautifulSoup(results.text,"html.parser").                                        
print(soup.prettify())====>But here i am getting the html output.Don't you think i shouldn't supposed to get output on this.

Comment: Yes, you are getting the HTML, of course, but if you will check the returned HTML with the HTML on the developer tools of any browser it will be different. As on the first request react is load, after this other data is being loaded by ajax requests.

Comment: create a script like this, load on to the browser, inspect code behind, <script> window.document.write("<html><body><h1>You see markups in Browser?</h1></body></html");</script>. If site is created this way, scraping the site for html markup may not work. Try it fun stuff.